# A proxy class as a generic replacement for getters and setters v2

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, template, proxy

Have you ever written proxy objects, instead of using a setter and a getter method? In that case, I'm interested in your opinion on the following design for a templated proxy.

This is a second version, after addressing comments from a [previous review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245747/64513); it is intended to work with C++11 or newer. Issues which have been addressed + changes:

- Support for `const` proxies.
- Move constructor.
- The getter possibly returning a reference, or some other funny type.
- `noexcept()` decoration
- `constexpr` decoration

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
#define CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 constexpr
#else
#define CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14
#endif


template <typename Handle, typename Getter, typename Setter>
class proxy {
public:
    using getter_return_type = decltype(std::declval<Getter>()(std::declval<Handle>()) );
        // Note: We assume the getter does not allow modifying the value. If it does - you don't
        // need the proxy in the first place. But _asserting_ this is difficult. For example, suppose
        // the getter returns an int*. Is the "actual" value an int, or an int*? We can't know that
        // without introducing yet another type parameter.

    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<getter_return_type>::type>::type;

    CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 
    operator getter_return_type() const noexcept(noexcept(getter_)) 
    { return getter_(handle_); }

    CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 proxy& 
    operator=(const value_type& x) noexcept(noexcept(setter_)) 
    { setter_(handle_, x); return *this; }

    CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 proxy& 
    operator=(value_type&& x) noexcept(noexcept(setter_))
    { setter_(handle_, std::move(x)); return *this; }

    CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 
    proxy(Handle handle, const Getter& getter, const Setter& setter) noexcept 
        : handle_(handle), getter_(getter), setter_(setter) { }

protected:
    const Handle handle_; 
        // Note: The handle is constant, not the referred-to element. So, _don't_ use a `T&` as your Handle, or
        // you'll be in trouble
    const Getter& getter_;
    const Setter& setter_;
        // Note: Attempts to use just plain Getter and Setter as the types here don't work when Getter/Setter
        // are function types
};

// Allows for template argument deduction during "construction" - before C++17
template <typename Handle, typename Getter, typename Setter>
CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CPP14 proxy<Handle, Getter, Setter>
make_proxy(const Handle& handle, const Getter& getter, const Setter& setter) noexcept
{
    return proxy<Handle, Getter, Setter>(handle, getter, setter);
}
```

And here are a couple of examples:

```
template <class T>
constexpr typename std::remove_const<T>::type& as_non_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return const_cast<typename std::remove_const<T>::type&>(t);
}

// This exists in C++14, but this example is compiled with C++11
template <class T>
constexpr typename std::add_const<T>::type& as_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}

const int& my_getter(int *x) { return *x; }
void my_setter(int *x, int val ) { *x = val; }

class foo {
public:
    using proxy_type = proxy<int*, decltype(my_getter), decltype(my_setter)>;
    proxy_type datum() {  return make_proxy(&x, my_getter, my_setter);  }
    const proxy_type datum() const { 
        return make_proxy(&as_non_const(x), my_getter, my_setter);
    }
protected:
    int x { 123 };
};

int example1()
{
    foo my_foo;

    my_foo.datum() = 456;
    return as_const(my_foo).datum();
}

double example2()
{
    double x=1;
    double coef=2.;
    auto pr = make_proxy(&x,
        [coef](double*x){return *x*coef;}, 
        [coef](double*x, double nx){*x = nx/coef;});
    pr = 8.;
    return as_const(pr);
}
```

See it all on <kbd>[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6GG9G817h)</kbd>.

Other than general comments, I'd appreciate help with:

- What do you think of my constexpr'ization? Is it reasonably executed? Should I even bother with it?
- Ditto regarding the use of `noexcept()`.
- Can I, and should I, make the `getter_` and `setter_` members into possibly-non-reference types?
- Is there any use to accepting the value type as an explicit template parameter?
- What if someone wants to use a `T&` as the handle? i.e. use `x` as the handle in the examples rather than `&x`, with appropriate getter and setter?
- What are your thoughts on comparison operators?

Answer (score 1):

### std::ref to the rescue

I believe that most of the places where references are used could be replaced with value type in the class and the user could just `std::ref()` their objects/callables (in this specific case, not in general). `std::reference_wrapper` provides implicit conversion to reference type (one of the main use cases include passing references to callables for `std::thread` and `std::bind`, as it decay copies by default). The other useful part of the wrapper is call operator, e.g. `operator()(...args)`. It takes whatever arguments are passed to it and simply forwards to the wrapped object.

At first glance it seems like there is undefined behavior in the example, as `make_proxy` is called with rvalues whose lifetime expires at the end of the expression, but they are still used afterwards.

Comment: 1. The user should not need to know about `std::ref()` or `std::reference_wrapper()` - I don't want to complicate their life. If relevant, I would need to take care of it within the class ctor and make_proxy.

Comment: @einpoklum it a decision users have to make conscious choice about. Trying to handle it in the class will probably lead to a tag type being required to differentiate between them or providing a different overload. The class just cannot make the decision without users help. If there is anything I am missing, perhaps you could provide slightly more specific example?

Comment: " undefined behavior in the example, as make_proxy is called with rvalues..." <- Won't the lifetime be extended by the const-references?

Comment: "it a decision users have to make conscious choice about. " <- disagree. Library users don't make conscious decisions about most of what you offer them... think of std::variant for example. There are lots of architectural choices in there which users are kept in the dark about. And that's fine. For this kind of a proxy class to have general appeal, it has to be simple and straightforward to use; and I won't shy away from a tag type for differentiating different setter and getter types, if it helps make the proxy easier to use from the outside.

Comment: @einpoklum about lifetime and const reference: think of it as NRVO/RVO. If you can apply RVO, then it will be extended. When the direction is inside the function the lifetime will be equal to expression containing the function call.

Comment: @einpoklum, about usage, perhaps I’m not understanding the context of usage, that is why I asked for a more concrete example. I am of the attitude of not doing excessive hand holding and trusting the user. I will definitely try my best to protect them from mistakes where possible, but I don’t want to write an abstraction that turns into a footgun. It is very hard to create an abstraction that doesn’t leak implementation details onto the user.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking both of using this in a [project of mine](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) ([here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/master/src/cuda/api/device.hpp) you can see a few get_XXX and set_XXX methods). But I'm also thinking of making it into a small library and offering it to people whose code I come to have a look at: "What, you have a setter and getter? Don't work this way, add a proxy! It's easy!"